# Use sp_WhoIsActive in AWS RDS (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, permissions, amazon-rds, sp-whoisactive

I'm trying to run Adam Machanic's `sp_WhoIsActive` in AWS RDS for SQL Server. When I run as the designated master account, say "TheAdmin", it works.  When I run as another user, say "AlmostAdmin", whom I've made a `db_owner` on the target DB, say "MyDB", it fails with permission errors like so:

```
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 342
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Note that, because you can't create any objects in the `master` DB in RDS, I had to create `sp_WhoIsActive` in the user DB `MyDB`, as stated.

Anybody had any luck making this work in RDS?  Thanks!

Other things I've tried:

- Granted `VIEW SERVER STATE` to "AlmostAdmin" and added him to server-roles `processadmin` and `setupadmin` to mirror "TheAdmin".
- Added "AlmostAdmin" to all other elevated DB roles in `MyDB` (yeah, I know, shouldn't make a difference, just grasping at straws).

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll answer myself, since it's working...

The required permissions **seem to be** as follows:

1. "AlmostAdmin" is a SQL Login in the `public` server role, `GRANT`ed securables "Connect SQL" and "View Server State".
2. The login is mapped to "AlmostAdmin" user in `MyDB`, which is in the `db_owner` role with default schema `dbo`.

My problem seems to have been with impersonation, because even though it fails for me when I run the following--

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'AlmostAdmin'
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
REVERT
```

--It works for the actual user when he's logged in himself (via SSMS).  And of course then I logged in as that user and verified that it was working for me too (when using that login, instead of my "TheAdmin" master login!).

Lesson learned: don't rely on impersonation 100% for testing security/permission issues; get the target user involved to test it out as well (or if you're in a position to know the credentials, lower yourself to that level and test it, instead of completely relying on `EXECUTE AS`).