# Can we use All first_responder kit / sp_whoisactive on AWS RDS SQL Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, performance-tuning

New to cloud (new project, starting this day) and have questions on AWS RDS SQL Server Instance. For the meantime, I don't have access do AWS Monitoring Tools (Cloud watch & Performance Insight), so I'm planning to use Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit & Adam's sp_whoisactive to check the database activities & performance issues of the RDS instance given to me. Want to know if these temporary solutions are effective? On my research, someone said that I run all these as temporary procs. Need advice the from the experts.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main#sp_blitz-overall-health-check) of First Responder Kit:

> Amazon RDS SQL Server - fully supported.

As far as sp_whoisactive is concerned, it is [supported](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive) on Azure.

> sp_WhoIsActive is a comprehensive activity monitoring stored procedure
> that works for all versions of SQL Server from 2005 through 2019 and
> Azure SQL DB.

You need to grant some permission for it to make it working on AWS RDS as highlighted in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148942/136766).

Hope this helps.